# Reading child node of a child node

Tags: c++, xml, qt

Below i have show a normal XML file:

```js
<Header>
  <Sub Name="" Value="" /Sub>
  <Sub Name="" value="" /Sub>
  .
  .
  .
  .
</Header>
```

I read the above mentioned XML like this:

```js
QStringList Name;
QStringList value;
QXmlGet xmlget;
xmlget.load(Sample.xml);
xmlget.findAndDescend("Header");
while(xmlget.findNext("Sub")
      {
      Name.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("Name". "Unknown"));
      value.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("value". "Unknown"));
      }
xmlget.save(Sample.xml);
```

But the xml i have right now is bit complicated.

XML:

```js
<Header>
  <Sub Name= "" Value = ""><Sub1 Name = ""></Sub1></Sub>
  <Sub Name= "" value = "" /Sub>
  <Sub Name= "" Value = ""><Sub1 Name = ""></Sub1></Sub>
   .
   .
   .
</Header>
```

Any suggestions how do I read the `<Sub1>`

Comment: Get a DOM parser like Xerces and walk the tree.

Comment: I would, but most of my code is based this parser, if it's entirely impossible to do the required action with this command i will change it to DOM parser

Answer (score 0):

Something like this one (Tested! It works!)

```
QStringList Name;
QStringList value;

QXmlGet xmlget;
xmlget.load("Sample.xml");
xmlget.findAndDescend("Header");

QXmlPut xmlPut(xmlget); // init reference from the variable - xmlget
while(xmlget.findNext("Sub")) {
    Name.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("Name", "Unknown"));
    value.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("Value", "Unknown"));
    xmlget.descend(); // now Sub is the parent element
    if( xmlPut.hasChildren() )  {
      while(xmlget.findNext("Sub1") { // finding relatively the parent - Sub 
          xmlPut.goTo(xmlget.element());
          xmlPut.setAttributeString("Name", "NAME1");
          xmlPut.setAttributeString("Value", "VALUE1");
      }
    } else {
       xmlPut.putInt("IntTag", "IntValue"); // We create the child node (IntTag) of the parent (Sub)
       xmlPut.setAttributeString("AttrName", "AttrValue"); // and add some attributes to it
    }
    xmlget.rise();

}
xmlPut.save("Sample.xml"); // Any file name to save the xml data
```

[docs](http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/other/qxmlputget-doc/classQXmlGet.html#a6cc12c23dccfb05c9216ad2df113a2a3)

Comment: Does not work, i did something similar like this. @Alexander Chernin. Hence this post. Can you please test it once?

Comment: @user5820174 I think this should work, with the exception that you need to add a call to QXmlGet::rise() at the end of the top while loop in order to return "up" to your previous position. Without that you are still searching for `xmlget.findNext("Sub")` as a child of `Sub`, when you want to be a level higher looking for childern of `Header`.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Thanks! totally works, any idea how do i write it back?

Comment: I want to write back the XML file. I dunno how to write the <Sub1>

Comment: @user5820174 look at the addition

Comment: @AlexanderChernin I do know how to save, i just don't know how to write <Sub1> just like i did not know how to read it.

Comment: @user5820174 Updated and tested. Try :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin. Thanks for your time, While writing ther won't be a <Sub1>, i need to create this. That was my problem. All subchild doesn't have it. Only few does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104963/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-user5820174).

Comment: That link is blocked  @AlexanderChernin

Comment: @AlexanderChernin any inputs?

Comment: Any ones, because you have QXmlPut::putString. Look the update at the top